# How to avoid getting invalid index value of textfield widgets when scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart

On Automation testing (not written in flutter, using third party tool), when I scrolling the screen index of each textformfields changing every time and it's not consistant.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(children: [
      TextFormField(),//1,
      TextFormField(),//2
       ///upto 14
    ]),
  );
```

Comment: What do you mean with invalid index? It's also not clear to me is this an error in the automation tool or in flutter? We can't help much if we don't even know how the automation happens. It sounds to me this is an error in the automation tool and maybe you should give more details about that

Comment: eg: before scrolling my textfield5 have index 5 but after scroll index for the same widget changing,